# Arduino variable with push button not updating correctly

Tags: arduino

So, what I'm trying to do with my Arduino is make it so it starts off with my variable, timestate, which is 0, then when the button is pressed, 1 is added to the variable. The LCD is meant to show my variable, but the number constantly stays at 0 even when I do press the button. I have tried making it so the button state is HIGH instead, but it just displays two 1s instead of changing the number.

I honestly have no idea if this is a problem with me not coding the variable, LCD or button correctly. What has gone wrong with my code? I'm quite new to Arduino so I'm very lost at the moment.

My code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

const int button1Pin = 1;


void setup() {
  

  pinMode(button1Pin, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

}

void loop() {

    int button1State;
    button1State = digitalRead(button1Pin);
  


    int timestate;
    timestate = 0;
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    //lcd.print(timestate);
    
    
    if (button1State == LOW)
    {
      timestate = timestate + 1;
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print(timestate);
      
      if (timestate == 10)
      {
        timestate = 0;
      }
           
    else
    {
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print(timestate);
    }
      
      
    }


}
```

[wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPEFh.jpg)

Comment: Your loop function sets timeState back to 0 every time through.  Try moving that third and fourth line of loop to global scope up before setup.

Comment: @Delta_G thank you so much! I can't believe I didn't notice that before.